# How to Call a Constructor from its Parametrized Constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-controls

How to Call a Constructor from its Parametrized Constructor?

Following is my user control code where I want to call two parametrized RouteBuilderPagerControl constructor from three parametrized RouteBuilderPagerControl.

```
public RouteBuilderPagerControl(GridPagingManager paging, GridTableView tableView)
{
  SetPager(paging, tableView);
  SetDataToControl();
}
public RouteBuilderPagerControl(GridPagingManager paging, GridTableView tableView, List<int> pageSizes)
{
  ddl.Items.Clear();
  pageSizes.Sort();
  foreach (int size in pageSizes)
  {
    ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(size.ToString() + " per page", size.ToString()));
  }
  SetPager(paging, tableView);
  SetDataToControl();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain constructors:

```
public RouteBuilderPagerControl(GridPagingManager paging, 
                                GridTableView tableView, 
                                List<int> pageSizes) 
    : this(paging, tableView)
```

This is described in MSDN - [Using Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173115.aspx).

In your case, you would want these two lines to only appear in the chained constructor:

```
SetPager(paging, tableView);
SetDataToControl();
```

Comment: will it be call before or after?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "this":

```
    public RouteBuilderPagerControl(GridPagingManager paging, GridTableView tableView, List<int> pageSizes) 
           : this(paging, tavleView)
    {
      ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call another constructor using the `this` keyword before the body of the constructor:

```
public RouteBuilderPagerControl(GridPagingManager paging, GridTableView tableView, List<int> pageSizes)
    :this(paging, tableView)
{
```

The other constructor will run *before* the body of the current constructor. You can't call it at an arbitrary point of the body. Another restriction here is that you can't access any instance methods/fields at that point.

In your case it looks like you want to call the other constructor after the current constructor, which is impossible in C#.